# Ajax GET requests not working asynchronously with Firefox due to page reload request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, asynchronous

I have the following code working properly with IE (11) and Chrome (58.0.3029.110), finally not with Firefox (53.0.3).

```
$('#uploadButton_home').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('uploadButton_home').onclick = false;
    $(this).css('opacity', 0.4)
    document.getElementById('uploadButton_home').ondblclick = false;
    
    var checkList = document.getElementsByClassName('uploadCheck');
    var upload = false;
    var filesnames = [];
    var nbCheck = $('.uploadCheck:checked').size()
    
    // for each file listed in page, only consider those checked
    for (var i = 0; i < checkList.length; i++) {
        if (checkList[i].checked) {
            upload = true;
            filename = checkList[i].id; //a file name
            filesnames.push(filename) // save the file name in a files names list
        }
    }
    
    if(upload) {
        var url = "saveUploadingfile?filesnames="+encode_url_symbols(filesnames)+"&username="+username;
        console.log('--- DEBUG -- saveUploadingfile - url =',url);    

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                  console.log('*** DEBUG *** saveUploadingfile SUCCESS');    
                  url = "upAllFiles?filesnames="+encode_url_symbols(filesnames)+"&username="+username;
                  console.log('--- DEBUG --- upAllFiles - url =',url);    
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                      console.log('--- DEBUG --- upAllFiles SUCCESS');    
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                      console.log('--- DEBUG --- upAllFiles ERROR - xhr.status',xhr.status,' - xhr.statusText',xhr.statusText,' - textStatus =',textStatus,' - thrownError=',thrownError);    
                    }
                  });
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                  console.log('--- DEBUG --- saveUploadingfile ERROR - xhr.status',xhr.status,' - xhr.statusText',xhr.statusText,' - textStatus =',textStatus,' - thrownError=',thrownError);    
            }
        });
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

In Firefox, the Network tab in the console does not show up any GET request actually sent.
Only the DEBUG messages from my code are shown:

> --- DEBUG --- saveUploadingfile - url = saveUploadingfile?filesnames=TestFile.txt&username=admin
>
> --- DEBUG --- saveUploadingfile ERROR - xhr.status 0  - xhr.statusText error  - textStatus = error  - thrownError=

With Firefox:

1. If I turn both the ajax GET requests to async:false, this works...
2. If I turn the 1st ajax GET request to async:false, and 2nd ajx GET to async:true, 1st request will succeed and 2nd will fail.

Note that I do not want the 2nd GET request to be synchronous in my context (because involving specific processing, then delay, on the server side).

I tried to make the use of `e.preventDefault()`, as code is triggered from a click on button, but with no change in behavior.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

## PROBLEM FIXED

Code modified as following (see  `document.location.reload(true);`):

```
$('#uploadButton_home').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('uploadButton_home').onclick = false;
    $(this).css('opacity', 0.4)
    document.getElementById('uploadButton_home').ondblclick = false;
    
    var checkList = document.getElementsByClassName('uploadCheck');
    var upload = false;
    var filesnames = [];
    var nbCheck = $('.uploadCheck:checked').size()
    
    // for each file listed in page, only consider those checked
    for (var i = 0; i < checkList.length; i++) {
        if (checkList[i].checked) {
            upload = true;
            filename = checkList[i].id; //a file name
            filesnames.push(filename) // save the file name in a files names list
        }
    }
    
    if(upload) {
        var url = "saveUploadingfile?filesnames="+encode_url_symbols(filesnames)+"&username="+username;
        console.log('--- DEBUG -- saveUploadingfile - url =',url);    

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                  console.log('*** DEBUG *** saveUploadingfile SUCCESS');    
                  url = "upAllFiles?filesnames="+encode_url_symbols(filesnames)+"&username="+username;
                  console.log('--- DEBUG --- upAllFiles - url =',url);    
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                      console.log('--- DEBUG --- upAllFiles SUCCESS');    
                      document.location.reload(true);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                      console.log('--- DEBUG --- upAllFiles ERROR - xhr.status',xhr.status,' - xhr.statusText',xhr.statusText,' - textStatus =',textStatus,' - thrownError=',thrownError);    
                    }
                  });
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                  console.log('--- DEBUG --- saveUploadingfile ERROR - xhr.status',xhr.status,' - xhr.statusText',xhr.statusText,' - textStatus =',textStatus,' - thrownError=',thrownError);    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are calling for page reload before requests have a chance. Also can't upload files this way. Read up on how to post `FormData` to upload files with ajax

Comment: `document.location.reload(true);` call in original code was the issue. Good catch Charlie !

Comment: I have moved this line of code into success callback of the 2nd GET request and this works well with Firefox. Works as good to with IE and Chrome.
Thanks a lot fo quick and efficient support !!!